# Issue with XSLT condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I need to pass BELNR value when the QUALF is "012" . If //E1EDK02/[QUALF=012]/BELNR is NULL then copy //E1EDK02/[QUALF=002]/BELNR

using following code but getting error as - **The context item for axis step xsl:document/element() is absent**

**Source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <E1EDK02>
        <QUALF>002</QUALF>
        <BELNR>0030000084</BELNR>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDK02>
        <QUALF>026</QUALF>
        <BELNR>0080000000</BELNR>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDK02>
        <QUALF>012</QUALF>
        <BELNR>0090000020</BELNR>
    </E1EDK02>
</DATA>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
    <Target>
        <BELNR>0090000020</BELNR>
    </Target>
</DATA>
```

**XSLT using**

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="DATA/E1EDK02[QUALF=012]/BELNR">
        <xsl:value-of select="DATA/E1EDK02[QUALF=012]/BELNR"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="DATA/E1EDK02[QUALF=002]/BELNR"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete code samples to allow us to reproduce the error easily, also tell us which XSLT processor you use. Is that code perhaps inside of an `xsl:function` where there is no context item?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "NULL": the element is missing or the element is empty.

Comment: XSLT 3 . NULL means missing

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the error you claim.